# Add formula expression instead of values in VBA Macro excel code

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm coding a VBA code to do some calculations on excel.
I have a cell with a number and I want another cell to have a **formula** based on the first one instead of having the calculated value of the formula. I've been trying using .Formula but it's not working:

```
'Ciclo
Cells(rowWhereToAddPhase, 6).Value = Round(3600 / Worksheets(originalSheet.Name).Cells(row, 22), 2)

'Prod/h
Cells(rowWhereToAddPhase, 7).Formula = "=Round(60 / Cells(rowWhereToAddPhase, 6).Value * 60, 0)"
```

When I try this I simply get error 400.

If, instead, I use this:

```
'Prod/h
Cells(rowWhereToAddPhase, 7).Value= Round(60 / Cells(rowWhereToAddPhase, 6).Value * 60, 0)
```

I just get a plain number.

Images, how it looks in the second case:

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ta0d.png)

How I'd like to have it:

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE0Zm.png)

I imagine the problem is how to call the cell: I use  `Cells(**rowWhereToAddPhase**, 6)` to refer to it because I don't know in what row it is, but I guess I should use another way.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cells(rowWhereToAddPhase, 7).Formula = _
   "=Round(60/" & Cells(rowWhereToAddPhase, 6).Address() & "*60,0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

.Formula needs to be a string whose content is the same as when you enter a formula manually in Excel (for example oRange.Formula = "=SUM(A5:C7)").

Try creating the formula in an Excel cell manually. Then when it works, set it via VBA, and perhaps use some string concatenation to get the variable rowWhereToAddPhase in there.